# Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm building a Flutter app that I am trying to make work on the web. Part of it contains some web specific code:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class DownloadViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const String url = 'https://example.com/api/v1/app/myapp_1.0.0.apk';
  void onAndroidDownloadPressed() {
    html.window.open(url, 'AndroidApp');
  }
}
```

However the `dart:html` import gives the following error:

> Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages

The longer version of the warning looks like this:

> Avoid using web libraries, `dart:html`, `dart:js` and `dart:js_util` in
>   Flutter packages that are not web plugins. These libraries are not
>   supported outside a web context; functionality that depends on them
>   will fail at runtime in Flutter mobile, and their use is generally
>   discouraged in Flutter web.
>
> Web library access is allowed in:
>
> ```
> plugin packages that declare web as a supported context
> ```
>
> otherwise, imports of `dart:html`, `dart:js` and `dart:js_util` are disallowed.

And it's not just a warning. This actually prevents building an Android or iOS app (even though this method isn't accessible from non-Web Flutter apps).

The only solution I've figured out is to comment out the import when I am building for Android and iOS and then uncomment it when I am building for the web. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package. It supports the browser, Dart VM, and Flutter and is a stand-in replacement for `dart:html` and other web related libraries.

```
dependencies:
  universal_html: ^1.2.1
```

Then instead of using `import 'dart:html' as html;` you can use the following import:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
```

For those who came to this page for other related web import problems (like `dart:js`), this plugin also supports the following imports:

```
import 'package:universal_html/driver.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/indexed_db.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/js.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/js_util.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/html.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/indexed_db.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/js.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/js_util.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/svg.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/web_gl.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/indexed_db.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/js.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/js_util.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/svg.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/web_gl.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/svg.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/web_gl.dart';
```

Comment: `universal_html: ^1.2.2` wouldn't work for me, but `universal_html: ^1.2.1` as shown in [the linked documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) did.

Comment: @StackUnderflow. OK, thanks for the notification. Maybe it is a bug in their versioning number. Anyway, I temporarily updated my answer to use `1.2.1`.

Comment: I was using FunctionStringCallback and it was causing this error. Try changing it to a final variable.

Comment: universal_html is unidentified, is there any alternative?

Comment: are you sure, because i am currently using dependencies: universal_html: ^2.2.4
And as an input i use import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
And it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

Since the merge of Flutter-web into the main Flutter repository, it's no longer possible to directly add imports for web libraries (e.g. dart:html, or dart:js) in a Flutter project on the main channel when targeting Web, Android and iOS.

Use the universal html package which provides extensive support for multiple platforms and web libraries.

1. From the root level of your project, command

   ```
   flutter pub add universal_html
   ```
2. ```
     import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html
   ```

This package isn't required to run some web files (e.g. dart:js). In my case, I just had to remove the import 'dart:js' import statement.