# Flutter Web Chrome - Error when clicking a button that calls a get request in an API

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, flutter, dart

I am running a flutter basic application via Google Chrome that has one button
This button when pressed calls an api that make a get request

```
consumeLogin() async {
    HttpClientRequest request = await new HttpClient().getUrl(url);
    print(request);
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    Stream repStream = response.transform(utf8.decoder);

    await for (var data in repStream) {
      print(data);
    }
  }
```

When I inspect the console I have this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._version
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:216)
    at Function._version (io_patch.dart:286)
    at Function.get version [as version] (platform_impl.dart:123)
    at get _version (platform.dart:76)
    at Function.desc.get [as _version] (operations.dart:816)
    at Function.get version [as version] (platform.dart:233)
    at Object._getHttpVersion (http_impl.dart:3371)
    at new _http._HttpClient.new (http_impl.dart:2154)
    at Function.new (http.dart:1517)
    at home_page.HomePage.new.consumeLogin (home_page.dart:81)
    at consumeLogin.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:86)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:125)
    at home_page.HomePage.new.consumeLogin (home_page.dart:79)
    at ink_well.InkWell.new.<anonymous> (home_page.dart:67)
    at _InkResponseState.new.[_handleTap] (ink_well.dart:772)
    at ink_well.dart:855
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (recognizer.dart:182)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (tap.dart:522)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.[_checkUp] (tap.dart:282)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.acceptGesture (tap.dart:254)
    at arena.GestureArenaManager.new.sweep (arena.dart:156)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (binding.dart:222)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (binding.dart:198)
```

What is happening?

Comment: Do you import dart:io library? Actually what is your libraries? Because usually some libraries cause this error because they don't work on web.

Comment: import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:convert';

I am importing those libraries

Comment: probably 'dart:io' cause this error because it is not able to use web. You need to find another library or solution unfortunately.

Comment: You're right! Thank you

Comment: Solved using answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945106/import-dartio-not-support-on-the-web-application