# GZipCodec().decode does not work in flutter for the target web. Is there a workaround?

Tags: flutter, dart, usda-fooddata-central-api

GZipCodec().decode does not work in flutter for the target web. Is there a workaround?
The following snippet works for the target 'android' and it works for the target 'windows'.

```
        List<int> gzipped = providerFDC.fdcdata_gzipped.codeUnits;
        final ungzipped0 = GZipCodec().decode(gzipped);
        String ungzipped = String.fromCharCodes(ungzipped0);
        List<dynamic> food = jsonDecode(ungzipped);
        foodList = food.map((e) => FoodItem.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

I am working on an app that uses Food Data Central database. A preliminary version can be already used at
http://buf1612huds2.w73.eu/foodd456/

Comment: Make sure you are using `archive` not `archive_io`. See: https://pub.dev/packages/archive

Answer (score 1):

The GZipCodec object is imported from the dart.io library, this library is not supported for Flutter Web.

A solution would be to use the [univerisal_io package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io), as also answered in the question: [import 'dart:io'; not support on the web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945106/import-dartio-not-support-on-the-web-application). Howver this library only allows you to compile for web while still using the dart.io references. But does not allow web clients to use the GZip decoding on web itself.